# How can I iterate & match the values from two different sized arrays until the longer array has been exhausted?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Say I have two arrays with the following values:

```
let array1 = (1,2,3,4);
let array2 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

How do I exhaustively assign the values from array2 so that all of them are assigned to a key from array1; like so:

```
let result = (
  1: {1,5},
  2: {2,6},
  3: {3,7},
  4: {4,8},
);
```

If there were 9 values in array 2 then it would continue looping until:

```
let result = (
  1: {1,5,9},
  2: {2,6},
  3: {3,7},
  4: {4,8},
);
```

In my real-world example, array1 will be minutes, so {1..60}, array2 will be an unknown number of dates (more than 60). I want to continue assigning the unknown number of dates a key until all dates are assigned a minute key from 1-60.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid JS. Please clarify your intent.

Comment: In addition to being invalid JS, The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Thanks to whoever posted and removed `array2.forEach((e, i) => { res[i % array1.length].push(e) });`. I don't use modulus often and didn't know it could be used like this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your question, one way to accomplish this is to implement array1 as a simple 2D array: an array of arrays.

```
let array1 = [[1],[2],[3],[4]];
let array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let row = 0;
let column = 0;
for (count = 0; count < array2.length; count++) {
    if (row >= array1.length) {
        row = 0;
        column++;
    }
    array1[row][column] = array2[count];
    row++;
}
consol.log(array1);
```

Try this quickly by going to the url "about:blank" and then right click somewhere and click inspect. Go to the console tab and paste the code above and press enter. Click the arrow from the output to expand the array and you should find that it worked as required. Also, not that it matters in your case, but this method of using the >= comparison instead of using % is faster for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let result = [];
for(let i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
    result[i] = [];
    for(let j=i; j<array2.length; j=j+array1.length) {
        result[i].push(array2[j]);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```